# How to conditionally style ReactJs material-table cell based on cell values?

Tags: material-ui, material-table

I am having a column in material-table with values like success,failed etc.
Based on these values I need to apply color on cell.
**How to achieve it using material-table**.

[image: Column with diff color for cells based on values]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This answer is specific to react [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/)

In the columns section we need to have something like mentioned below, so when data is rendered in the table it will conditionally apply style based on cell values.

```
    {
    title: 'Status', field: 'status',
        render: rowData => {
            return
            rowData.status == "Pending" ? <p style={{ color: "#E87722", fontWeight: "bold" }}>{rowData.status}</p> :
                rowData.status == "SUCCESS" ? <p style={{ color: "#008240", fontWeight: "bold" }}>{rowData.status}</p> :
                    <p style={{ color: "#B0B700", fontWeight: "bold" }}>{rowData.status}</p>
        }
}
```

Comment: is anyway is there to put debugger inside render? I want to check the value rowData ?

Comment: I m surprised why this isn't somewhere visible in the docs i spent hours trying to get this work and was about to use something else. Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

I added the style in the columns declaration.

```
const columns = [
    { title: "ID", field: "_id" },
    { title: "Email", field: "email" },
    {
      title: "First Login",
      field: "first_login",
      cellStyle: (e, rowData) => {
        if (!rowData.first_login) {
          return { color: "red" };
        }
      },
    },
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need classes which every of them has the style you desire then you can find some

```
  <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
  <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
  <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
  <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
```

in your matrial Ui code , then you need to create some span in which there will be values of table for example :

```
  <TableCell align="right">
       <span>{row.value}</span>
  </TableCell>
```

then you need to check what your value is , for example if it is success return the class 
you want and if it is something els give span some other class

```
  <TableCell align="right">
      <span className={row.value === "success" ? "text-success" : "text-warning"}>{row.value}</span>
  </TableCell>
```

Hope this help you

Comment: this is not related to OP's question this is simple table styling he is talking about Material-Table its a separate package.

Comment: @HadiPawar Right , this question has 2 hashtags Material-UI and Material-Table , i think it's not a bad idea to keep this answer for those who will looking for Material-Ui table answer, it might help someone in future , Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 0):

[Table Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfWlH.png)

```
{ title: 'Status', field: 'status',render: rowData => {                                         
                                            
return(
    rowData.status == "TODO" ? <div><span style={{color: 'gray'}}><i className="fas fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"/></span> {" "}{" "} Todo</div> :
    rowData.status == "Done" ? <div><span style={{color: 'Green'}}><i className="fas fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"/></span> {" "}{" "}Done</div> :
    rowData.status == "Pending Review" ? <div><span style={{color: 'gray'}}><i className="fas fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"/></span> Pending Review</div> :
    rowData.status == "Approved" ? <div><span style={{color: 'yellow'}}><i className="fas fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"/></span> Approved</div> :
    rowData.status == "Rejected" ? <div><span style={{color: 'red'}}><i className="fas fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"/></span> Rejected</div> :
    rowData.status == "In Progress" ? <div><span style={{color: 'gray'}}><i className="fas fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"/></span> In Progress</div> :
    rowData.status == "Inspection Complete" ? <div><span style={{color: 'yellow' }}><i className="fas fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"/></span> Inspection Complete</div> :
     <span>{rowData.status}</span>
)}}
```

> Url for meterial table https://material-table.com